# Ubuntu Desktop user login only terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome, 22.04

Is there any way to produce the following Ubuntu experience for two users of the same machine?

- Turn the Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 VM on.
- Presented with the gnome lock screen.
- Sign in as user-2.
- Command line only experience.
- Log out.
- Presented with the gnome lock screen.
- Sign in as user-1.
- Gnome experience.

I hope that made sense. Basically, on the same computer, is there a way for one user to have a desktop display while the other user has command line only?

Comment: press ctrl+alt+F4 at the login screen for  tty terminal. Then press ctrl+alt+f1 to go back.